# Undefined index in YII

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie to YII. I don't know if this que might be too silly, but I am unable to figure it out.

I have a view with basic fields and a browse button to upload files. 
I have written the required rules in models too.

view-

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'contact-form',
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); 
?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'filename');?>  //filename is defined here
<?php  echo $form->error($model, 'filename');?
```

controller-

```
$model=new ContactForm;
if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
if($model->validate())
{
    // Some code;
 var_dump($_FILES['filename']); /**ERROR HERE**/
}
}
```

I have defined "filename" in view,model and controller. Yet, it displays error as "undefined index". If the problem is with redirecting it correctly, then why am I able to correctly dump other fields in my page? The problem is only with one field. Please help me find out my mistake.

Comment: Can you show full error text?

Comment: Undefined index: filename  is the error and pointing to the line var_dump($FILES['filename'])

Comment: Please show your ContactForm model.

Comment: Simply lookup the name of the file input in your frontend and use this prepend to `_filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$uploadFile=  CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename');
if($uploadFile !== null){
$name= $uploadFile->name;
$path= $uploadFile->tempName;
}else{
echo 'NO File Uploaded';
exit();
}
```

And if you want to dump the data then you should use this

```
var_dump($_FILES['ContactForm_filename']);
```